# Why am I getting error messages in my "customer.cpp" file

Tags: c++, undefined, getline

I am unsure about why I am getting this error message when I hover over `purchaseArray` in my `string Customer::save()` method in the `customer.cpp` file:

> identifier is undefined

And this error message when I hover over `getline` in the `void Customer::parse(string line)` method in the `customer.cpp` file:

> no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::stringstream, int, char)

Code in the `Customer.cpp` file:

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

//default constructor
Customer::Customer() {
}


//Full constructor
Customer::Customer(int customerID, string title, string name, int numOfPurchases, int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3, string type)
{
    this->customerID = customerID;
    this->title = title;
    this->name = name;
    this->numOfPurchases = numOfPurchases;
    purchases = new int[3];
    purchases[0] = purchase1;
    purchases[1] = purchase2;
    purchases[2] = purchase3;
    this->type = type;
}

Customer::Customer(const Customer& source) //copy constructor
{
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
    this->customerID = source.customerID;
    this->title = source.title;
    this->name = source.name;
    this->numOfPurchases = source.numOfPurchases;
    this->purchases = new int[3];
    purchases[0] = source.purchases[0];
    purchases[1] = source.purchases[1];
    purchases[2] = source.purchases[2];
    this->type = source.type;
}

//overloaded assignment operator=
Customer& Customer::operator= (Customer& otherCustomer)
{
    cout << "Overloaded assignment operator= called" << endl;

    //self-assignment guard
    if (this == &otherCustomer)
        return *this;  //refernce to the same object

   // copy data from the source (rhs) to this object (the destination)
    name = otherCustomer.name;

    //must make a new scores object to store a copy of the other student 
    if (purchases != nullptr)
        delete[] purchases;

    purchases = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        purchases[i] = otherCustomer.purchases[i];
    }

    //return this existing object so we can chain this operator 
    return *this;
}

string Customer::save()
{
    stringstream out;
    out << this->customerID << ";";
    out << this->title << ";";
    out << this->name << ";";
    out << this->numOfPurchases << ";";
    int* purchases = 0;
    purchases = purchases | (purchaseArray[0] << 24);
    purchases = purchases | (purchaseArray[1] << 16);
    purchases = purchases | (purchaseArray[2] << 8);
    out << this->type << ";";
    out.flush();
    return out.str();
}

void Customer::parse(string line)
{
    stringstream in(line);
    string customerIDLine;
    getline(in, customerIDLine, ';');
    customerID = stoi(customerIDLine);
    getline(in, title, ';');
    getline(in, name, ';');

    int numOfPurchases;
    getline(in, numOfPurchases, ';');
    int s = stoi(numOfPurchases);

    purchasesArray[0] = (s & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
    purchasesArray[1] = (s & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
    purchasesArray[2] = s & 255;

    getline(in, type, ';');
}  

Customer::~Customer() {
    cout << "Destructor ~Customer called" << endl;
    delete[] purchases;
}

// Overloaded insertion operator  (Outputs Character object data as an output stream)
// Defined in header file as a  "friend" function, as it is not a member function
//
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Customer& customer)
{
    cout << "Customer details ( output by insertion operator<< )" << endl;
    cout << "Customer ID: " << customer.customerID << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << customer.title << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << customer.name << endl;
    cout << "Number of purchases: " << customer.numOfPurchases << endl;
    cout << "Purchases: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0) cout << ",";
        cout << customer.purchases[i];
    }
    cout << "Type: " << customer.type << endl;
    
    return out;
}


istream& operator>> (istream& in, Customer& customer)
{
    cout << "Enter Customer details ( using the extraction operator>> )" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Customer ID: " << endl;
    cin >> customer.customerID;
    cout << "Enter Title: " << endl;
    getline(cin, customer.title);
    cout << "Enter Name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, customer.name);
    cout << "Enter Number of Purchases: ";
    cin >> customer.numOfPurchases; 
    cout << "Enter Purchases: ";
    cin >> customer.purchases[0];
    cin >> customer.purchases[1];
    cin >> customer.purchases[2];
    cout << "Enter Type";
    getline(cin, customer.type);
    cout << endl;

    return in;
}

int Customer::getCustomerID()
{
    return customerID;
}

string Customer::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

string Customer::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Customer::getNumOfPurchases()
{
    return numOfPurchases;
}

int* Customer::getPurchases()
{
    return purchases;
}

string Customer::getType()
{
    return type;
}

void Customer::setCustomerID(int customerID)
{
    if (customerID < 1) {
        cout << "Customer ID has to be equal to 1 or more" << endl; //Changed all the "throw invalid_argument" messages to cout as they were causing an issue with my main.cpp file and an abort message kept appearing every time I ran my main.cpp file.
    }
    this->customerID = customerID;
}

void Customer::setTitle(string title)
{
    if (title.length() < 2) {
        cout << "Title has to be more than or equal to 2 characters" << endl;
    }
    this->title = title;
}

void Customer::setName(string name)
{
    if (name.length() < 4) {
        cout << "Length of name should be more than or equal to 4 characters" << endl;
    }
    this->name = name;
}

//Got help ith this on stack overflow as I was using "&&" instead of using "||" for the if statement
void Customer::setNumOfPurchases(int numOfPurchases)
{
    if(numOfPurchases <0 || numOfPurchases > 10000){
        cout << "Number of purchases should be between 0 to 10000" << endl;
    }
    this->numOfPurchases = numOfPurchases;
}

void Customer::setPurchases(int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3)
{
    if (purchase1 < 0 || purchase2 < 0 || purchase3 < 0) {
        cout << "Purchases must be more than or equal to zero" << endl;
    }
}

//Got help from stack overflow on comparing strings as I originally didnt use "type.compare"
void Customer::setType(string type) {
    if (type.compare("New") !=0 || type.compare("Either") !=0) {
        cout << "Type of purchase has to be New or Either" << endl;
    }
}
```

Code in the `Customer.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>

class Customer
{
private:
    int customerID;
    string title;
    string name;
    int numOfPurchases;
    int* purchases;
    string type;

public:
    Customer(); // default constructor
    Customer(int customerID, string title, string name, int numOfPurchases, int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3, string type);
    
    //copy overload assignment
    Customer& operator=(Customer& otherCustomer);
    Customer(const Customer& source);

    string save();
    void parse(string line);
    ~Customer(); //destructor


    //Getters and Setters
    void setCustomerID(int customerID);
    void setTitle(string title);
    void setName(string name);
    void setNumOfPurchases(int numOfPurchases);
    void setPurchases(int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3);
    void setType(string type);

    int getCustomerID();
    string getTitle();
    string getName();
    int getNumOfPurchases();
    int* getPurchases();
    string getType();

    void printCustomer() {
        cout << customerID << "," << title << "," << name << "," << numOfPurchases << "," << purchases << "," << type << endl;
    }

    

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Customer& customer); // overloaded operator<<
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Customer& customer); // overloaded operator >>
};
```

Code from the `Main.cpp` file:

```
// Repeat_Assessment_C++_AislingSmith.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;


void OutputFileStream();
void parseLine(const string& str);
void InputFileStream();
void save(vector<Customer> customers);
void load(vector<Customer>& customers);
void addCustomer(vector<Customer>& vect);
//void printActions();


void OutputFileStream()
{
    cout << "Creating and writing to file: Customer.txt" << endl;

    ofstream outStream("customers.txt");  // write mode (overwrites existing data)

    if (outStream.good())
    {
        int customerID = 150033;
        outStream << "This is a line of text.\n";
        outStream << "This is another line of text.\n";
        outStream << "This is a line of text.\n";
        int numOfPurchases = 4;
        int purchases = 0;
        outStream << customerID << "Mr" << "Jack" << "New" << numOfPurchases << purchases << endl;

        outStream.close(); //  close file
        cout << "File written.\n" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
}

void parseLine(const string& str) {

    stringstream strStream(str); //create string stream from the string
   // int customerID;
    string title;
    string name;
    string type;
    //int numOfPurchases;
    //int purchases;
    string s;
   
    int customerID = 150033;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    customerID = stoi(s);

    getline(strStream, title, ';');
    getline(strStream, name, ';');
    getline(strStream, type, ';');

    int numOfPurchases = 4;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    numOfPurchases = stoi(s);

    int purchases = 0;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    purchases = stoi(s);
    int* purchasesArray = new int[3];
    purchasesArray[0] = (purchases & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
    purchasesArray[1] = (purchases & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
    purchasesArray[2] = purchases & 255;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int purchasesArray[3];
    }

    cout << " CustomerID: " << customerID << "Title:" << title << " Name: " << name << " Type:" << type << " Number of Purchases: " << numOfPurchases << "Purchases: " << purchases << endl;
}

void InputFileStream() {
    cout << "Reading from a semi-colon delimited txt file" << endl;

    string line;
    ifstream inStream("customers.txt"); //opens file as an input file stream
    if (inStream.good()) //if the file is opened successfully and not empty
    {
        while (getline(inStream, line)) //reads line until false return
        {
            parseLine(line);
        }
        inStream.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "unable to open file or the file is empty!";
}

void save(vector<Customer> customers)
{
    ofstream out("customers.txt");
    if(out)
    {
        for (Customer& c : customers)
        {
            out << c.save();
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error Writing to File" << endl;
    }
}

void load(vector<Customer>& customers)
{
    ifstream in("customers.txt");
    if (in) {
        string line;
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            getline(in, line);
            if (line != "")
            {
                Customer c;
                c.parse(line);
                customers.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }
}

void addCustomer(vector<Customer>& customers) {
    Customer customer;
    cin >> customer;
    customers.push_back(customer);
    
}



int main()
{
    InputFileStream();
    vector<Customer> customers;
    Customer c;

    Customer cust1;

    cust1.setCustomerID(150032);
    cust1.setTitle("Mr");
    cust1.setName("Joey");
    cust1.setNumOfPurchases(3);
    cust1.setPurchases(366, 352, 334);
    cust1.setType("New");

    cout << cust1.getCustomerID() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getTitle() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getName() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getNumOfPurchases() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getPurchases() << endl;
    cout <<  cust1.getType() << endl;
   
    


    return 0;
   

}
```

Comment: Where is `purchaseArray` defined? It looks like you may be trying to reference the array `purchases`.

Comment: When you hover? Did you try to compile it? If no, compile it first. The compiler message is often more precise than intellisense. Then please provide the exact error message.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { int purchasesArray[3]; }` – what exactly are you expecting this  loop to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

#### First Problem

The first error is pretty clear, `purchaseArray` is nowhere defined (at least not in the code you show here) and you probably meant just `purchases` or `this->purchases`? Allthough I got no clue what you tried to achieve with the `int *purchases` there.

#### Second Problem

The second one occurs, because the way you try to read an integer from a stream is flawed.
It's about this piece of code from `Customer::parse`

```
int numOfPurchases; // declare int 
getline(in, numOfPurchases, ';'); // error, second parameter must be std::string!
int s = stoi(numOfPurchases); // numOfPurchases is already an int
```

You probably wanted this:

```
std::string numOfPurchasesBuf; // temporary buffer
getline(in, numOfPurchasesBuf, ';'); // read data to string
int s = stoi(numOfPurchasesBuf); // convert to int
```

and since all of those lines read some member variable you probably want to set this one as well:

```
this->numOfPurchases = s;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The int* purchases is a pointer to a dynamic array, in the parse method should I change it to something similar to the "numOfPurchases" you just fixed? sorry i'm only new to c++

Comment: No, it's just an `int*` that points to no real data (it's initialized to 0, so it's the same as `nullptr`). Then you do some binary operations on it that look like you want to put 3 8-bit values in one 32-bit value (which is ok and common practice if needed, but should be done on integers, not pointers). But you don't even use this pointer afterwards, so I'm a bit clueless what this is supposed to do.